# Methods with the same name

Tags: php

My webpage gives the "methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of php" error with the below code.

When I change the "function settings()" to "function __construct()", the web page gives a fatal error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method validator::settings() in /home/mertcek1563/public_html/rmd2015/sdwf/validator.php:11 
Stack trace: 
    #0 /home/mertcek1563/public_html/rmd2015/z_common.php(103): validator->__construct() 
    #1 /home/mertcek1563/public_html/rmd2015/z_core.php(22): include('/home/mertcek15...') 
    #2 /home/mertcek1563/public_html/rmd2015/index.php(2): include('/home/mertcek15...') 
    #3 {main} 
thrown in /home/mertcek1563/public_html/rmd2015/sdwf/validator.php on line 11
```

How I can fix this code?

```
class settings
{   
    var $settings = array();

    function settings(){

        $this->settings["price"]=array();
        $this->settings["price"]["dot"]=".";
        $this->settings["price"]["decimals"]=6;

        $this->settings["date"]=array();
        $this->settings["date"]["delimiter"]="/";
        $this->settings["date"]["format"]="dd/mm/yyyy";

        $this->settings["number"]=array();
        $this->settings["number"]["dot"]=".";
        $this->settings["number"]["decimals"]=6;

    }

}
```

Then I end up with fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
> validator::settings() in
> /home/mertcek1563/public_html/rmd2015/sdwf/validator.php:11

```
<?
include_once("settings.php");

class validator extends settings
{
    var $errors = array();
    var $required = array();    

    function __construct(){
        
        $this->settings();

    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Barmar Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method validator::settings() in /home/mertcek1563/public_html/rmd2015/sdwf/validator.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /home/mertcek1563/public_html/rmd2015/z_common.php(103): validator->__construct() #1 /home/mertcek1563/public_html/rmd2015/z_core.php(22): include('/home/mertcek15...') #2 /home/mertcek1563/public_html/rmd2015/index.php(2): include('/home/mertcek15...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/mertcek1563/public_html/rmd2015/sdwf/validator.php on line 11

Comment: That error message is about a `settings` method in `class validator`, not `class settings`

Comment: @Barmar What could be the issue in below validator.php then? <?
include_once("settings.php");

class validator extends settings
{
 var $errors = array();
 var $required = array(); 

 function __construct(){

  $this->settings();

Comment: Please put the code in the question, not comments.

Comment: Read the **NOTE** [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: `$this->settings()` should be `parent::__construct()`

Comment: @Barmar God bless you.